# Not able to connect to MongoDB using NPM. URI issue?

Tags: mongodb, npm

So, I am not able to connect to MongoDB (Atlas). Feels like I may be going crazy here as logs are about as helpful as an anchor on a sinking boat. Here's what's going on. **Thanks for the help.**

**Here's my server.js file:**

```
'use strict';

const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const http = require('http');
const nconf = require('nconf');
let uri = 'mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-w4hci.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority;';
```

**Here's what console is saying**

```
npm start

> test@1.0.0 start /home/XXXXXXX
> node server.js

mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-w4hci.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority;

/home/XXXXXXX/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:421
          throw err
          ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-w4hci.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-w4hci.mongodb.net cluster0-w4hci.mongodb.net:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/XXXXXXX/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/XXXXXXX/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/XXXXXXX/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/XXXXXXX/.npm/_logs/2020-02-23T15_17_31_259Z-debug.log
```

Comment: you are whitelisted?

Comment: Good question. I allowed 0.0.0.0/0. Is there something else I should unlock?

Comment: Are you sure `0.0.0.0/0` is your IP address? If no, you can check your IP address using: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1696588

Comment: In the database URI, did you deliberately remove the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` value for the question post or that is exactly how it is written in the code you are running on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have my IP added. And, the IP from GCP. I intentionally hid username and password. But, the real connection string has the correct one.

Comment: So, I didn't encode special characters and that could have been it. But, I just tried again with a simpler password and same error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my node.js driver was a different version than what I thought. Once I selected the correct version from Atlas, the URI worked and I am not connected!